# My images are not shown in a recyclerView in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-device-manager

Hello i am using this emulator created for M1 machines https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview . i am getting the poster path from the moviesApi.however in other devices they paint well in the recyclerview and when i emulate it in my moto g6 this problem also happens.

[image]

The images displayed are the ones set in the xml as follows.

```
  <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rv_image_movie"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@drawable/movies_noimage"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            </ImageView>
```

The retrofit response is perfect and as i commented it works in other emulator api 26 27 28 any you name it. But in this one and in motog6 doesnt work something must be wrong.

[image: This is the end result!]

This is weird because in the m1 supported emulator my rick and morty app shows images perfectly.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Ok i found the answer to this and it might help lots of people. To fix this issue you need to add in your android manifest...

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:name=".MovieApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

    android:theme="@style/Theme.MoviesDBKotlin">
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MoviesDBKotlin">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" will fix the emulator problem something to do with glide in my case i think so . Enjoy!!.

Comment: The problem is no with the glide! It's because you're trying to load images from a non-HTTPS link. Use the HTTPS version and the problem will be fixed. By default, loading resources from an HTTP version is restricted.

Comment: in the newer apis from 9 and onwards (maybe from 8+) you have to use HTTPS otherwise your network call will be blocked.

Comment: wow nice both of you are right anyways i think we helped other people with this post . and thank you for responce